# Import Once JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react, google, recaptcha

Tenho dois componentes no meu projeto em ReactJs, que usam o google recaptcha. Porém, como são dois, cada vez que eu chamo ele é como se ele entendesse que eu quisesse carregar o "import ReCaptcha from 'react-recaptcha';"
Queria saber com faço pra importar apenas na primeira vez, pois quando vou pro segundo componente que usa ele, da um erro dizendo que: reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element

Comment: Os dois componentes renderizam o recaptcha? Há a necessidade dos dois renderizar? Existem métodos do ciclo de vida que vc consegue controlar o que fazer antes e depois do componente ser montado.

Answer (score 0):

tudo bem? Você não postou um trecho do seu código, então vou assumir que estes dois componentes estão separados, claro, e sendo chamados por outro componente, tipo assim:
Index
->Comp1
->Comp2

O ideal seria usar o Index pra chamar o Recaptcha. Ainda não usei essa função, mas seria algo desse tipo:

```js
// index.js ou outro arquivo de entrada
import React, { Component } form 'react';
import Recaptcha from 'react-recaptcha;
import Component1 from '../seu_caminho';
import Component2 from '../seu_caminho'

export default class Index extends Component {
  handleRecaptcha = (algumParametro_ou_nao) => {
    // Funcao que vai chamar o recaptcha e retornar algo
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Compoment1 handleRecaptcha={() => this.handleRecaptcha()} /> // se tiver parametros passe ali nos parenteses
     <Component2 /> // Se precisar, passe a função recaptcha aqui tbm
    );
  }
}
```

Dentro de cada componente essa função vira um Props ai é só chamar com `this.props.handleRecaptcha()`
Espero que isso te ajude.
Até.